# two vertical scroll bars

Tags: html, css, forms

I want to remove the scrollbar inside the div without losing the look of the survey form. Is this possible? I want the elements displayed on each other and only 1 scroll bar on display

I tried `overflow: scroll` `display: block` but I haven't hacked it yet

The website im working on:

https://codepen.io/Random_user42/pen/dyKLwzE?editors=1100

Comment: So do you want to have the survey form scrollable but the scroll bar hidden?
Or do you want the survey form to be in the page but not scrollable and rather have the whole page to be scrollable?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the height inner div to 100vh. Delete that line and your inner div will not show a scrollbar.

```
#form{
  ...
  height: 100vh;
  ...
}
```

Comment: glad to be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to hide both the horizontal and vertical scrollbar.

Like

```
#form{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

And if you came across to hide only vertical or only horizontal  scroll-bar
Then you can go ahead by following this To only hide the vertical scrollbar, or only the horizontal scrollbar, use `overflow-y` or `overflow-x` respectively!

```
#form {

  overflow-y: hidden; /* Hide vertical scrollbar */

  overflow-x: hidden; /* Hide horizontal scrollbar */

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `overflow` to `auto` change overflow to not show a scrollbar.

```css
    #form{
      position: relative;
      margin: auto;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow-x: auto;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      width: 60vw;
      background-color:rgba(27, 27, 50, 0.8);
      color: white;
  }
```